# How connect to local TFS 2015 from visual studio code(angular project)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, version-control, tfs-2015, tfvc

For version control I'm using locally installed TFS 2015 , and I want to  upload my angular project from visual studio code to this server.
As far I've researched I did not find how connect vscode to tfs 2015.

Comment: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#vscode-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [got all options documented on my blog](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#vscode-versions):

### TFS 2015 update 2 or higher

- [Install Azure Repos Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)
- `tf` commandline

  - Any version of [Team Explorer 2015+](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer)
  - Or [Team Explorer Anywhere CLC](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/)

[Configuration is explained here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team).